# align Label and Text Area in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

i create a frame like this. but i don't know how to align this. [image]

I want timed off version 1.1 is center on the top and in next line Subject label followed by subject text box and in next line body label followed by body text box.

And in text box when i type more, it not bounce to next time. the text goes to invisible but enter in same line. i hope you help me. and sorry i'm not good in English.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The type you want to learn about is _LayoutManager_ :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the layut manager.

Start by taking a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Personally, I'd recommend `GridBagLayout`, it is the most flexible, but also the most complex layout manager available in the default libraries

You may also find [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) of some use

**Update With Example**

Take a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout27 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout27();
    }

    public TestLayout27() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Timedoff Version 1.1", JLabel.CENTER);
            l1.setBackground(Color.red);
            l1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
            JLabel l2 = new JLabel("subject:");
            JTextField b = new JTextField("subject", 15);
            JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Body:");
            JTextArea a1 = new JTextArea("boby", 10, 20);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            add(l1, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(l2, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(b, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(l3, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(a1, gbc);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: thanku @MadProgrammer. it really help me.. but i try to add a button JButton but=new JButton("send"); and in last line i add like gbc.gridy++; add(but,gbc);  ... the complete structure is changed. when i remove that button, i comes back to original.. how can i add button???